# Excel VBA - If v in rng 1 > x and v in rng 2 < y then do something

Tags: vba, excel

I have values in 2 ranges that will determine if a cell is highlighted or not.  The logic is below, but I can't seem to figure out the correct VBA code.

```
Dim earlyLeave As Range, tCOut As Range, tMOwed As Range

For Each earlyLeave In Range("A31:A37")
     If x in range("g21:g27") > 20 And y in range("b31:b37") < 0 Then
          ......(highlight formatting)........
     End If
Next earlyLeave
```

Edit: with correct variables in response to below answer:

```
    Dim earlyLeave As Range, tCOut As Range, tMOwed As Range

    For Each earlyLeave In Range("A31:A37")
        For Each tCOut In Range("G21:G27")
            If tCOut.Value > 20 Then
                For Each tMOwed In Range("B31:B37")
                    If tMOwed.Value < 0 Then
                        Selection.FormatConditions.Interior.Color = 255
                    End If
                Next tMOwed
            End If
        Next tCOut
    Next earlyLeave
```

Edit: screenshot with current spreadsheet is below.  I need the cells in range a31:a37 to highlight a color (for now, 255, red) if the value in g21:g27 is less than 20 and/or the value in b31:b37 is greater than 0.  The values for person a should match a, b to b, and so on...

[image]

Comment: Can't figure out what exactly you are trying to achieve ? the 2 ranges do not overlap (not in rows or columns), can you share a screen-shot of what you want to achieve here ? What range exactly should be the `Selection` ?

Comment: @Shai, the edit is above

Comment: so actually, when you check `"B31" > 0` it only matters if `"G21 < 20` (not the entire range "G22:G27" since the value in column A for these rows is not `a`, correct ?

Comment: Correct, b31 and g21 correspond to a31.  And so on.

Comment: try my code below

Comment: commenting below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below using the `Application.Match` function to find the relevant row in `Range("A21:A27")` that correlates with the relevant `Range("A31:A37")`.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AnalystTst()

Dim earlyLeave As Range, tCOut As Range, tMOwed As Range
Dim RowMatch As Variant

For Each tMOwed In Range("B31:B37")
    If tMOwed.Value > 0 Then
        tMOwed.Offset(, -1).Interior.Color = 255
    Else
        'find the relevant row in Range("A21:A27") using the Match Function
        RowMatch = Application.Match(tMOwed.Offset(, -1).Value, Range("A21:A27"), 0)
        If Not IsError(RowMatch) Then '<-- successful Match
            If Range("G" & Range("A21:A27").Row + RowMatch - 1).Value < 20 Then
                tMOwed.Offset(, -1).Interior.Color = 255
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next tMOwed

End Sub
```

Comment: The only edit I need is that A31:A37 are the cells that need to be highlighted based off of the values in B31:B37 and G21:G27

Comment: Okay, now it is partially working (wasn't at all before..).  A31 and A36 are highlighted, as they should be.  However, so should A33, A35, and A37, since each was below 20 in range(G21:G27)

Comment: @sbagnato  not according to your post, you wanted the values in column B > 0, no ?

Comment: if the value in col B > 0 an/or value in col G <20, then highlight A

Comment: @sbagnato  and /or, which one ? You are not clear what r the rules to color column A in red

Comment: I greatly apologize.  It should be Or.

Comment: @sbagnato let's hope 3rd time is a charm, try now

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim earlyLeave As Range

For Each earlyLeave In Range("A31:A37")
      If Range("G" & (earlyLeave.Row-10)).Value < 20 or Range("B" & (earlyLeave.Row)).Value > 0 Then
         earlyLeave.Interior.Color = RGB(255,0,0) 
      End If
Next earlyLeave
```

Now edited to be closer to various comments

Comment: Not appearing to work right....I edited the OP so that you can see what the code is after I fixed the variables

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Conditional Formatting for this task.
select the Cells then 
Under Home Tab/conditional Formatting
/use a formula to determine which cells to Format/

add the follow expression

```
=($C21<20)+($b31>0)
```

and then set format fill color to Red.
This will render way faster then any VBA code can run.